# Isortable<T> implementation

Tags: c#

i have a `SortableList<T>` class that implements `ISortable<T>`. I am having hard time to implement below two members of interface..

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    //Is this right? 
    return this.List.GetEnumerator();
}

#endregion

#region IEnumerable<T> Members

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    // how i am gona implement it?

}
```

and here is the code for whole class . Any help will be appreciated

```
public class SortedList<T> : ISortable<T>
{
    public List<T> List { get; private set; }
    public string Sort { get; private set; }
    public string Order { get; private set; }
    public SortedList(List<T> list, string sort = null, string order = null)
    {
        List = list;
        Sort = sort;
        Order = order;
    } 
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {

    }
}
```

And ISortable is here

```
public interface ISortable : IEnumerable
    {
        string Sort { get; }
        string Order { get; }
    }
```

and here is ISortable of T

```
public interface ISortable<T> : ISortable, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        // No members..
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `ISortable<T>`? An interface with no members is a bad code smell.

Comment: i agree @EricLippert. I was just playing around and then i forgot to change it. Thanks : ) .. Have moved Sort and Order to ISortable<T> ... Thank You Again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement all that both methods by doing something like this:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<T>) this).GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.List.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank You .. I appreciate it